# "psql: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above" when connecting using psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using the command `psql -U <username> -W` to connect to a Postgres server running on localhost under Ubuntu (via WSL2). After entering the password manually, the command errors out with the message: `psql: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above`

It must be a problem with `psql` itself because I am able to connect to the database successfully using the Datagrip application.

What are the steps to fix this?

Comment: Install (or use) a newer version of psql, at least version 10

Comment: Prior to version 10 of postgresql, the `password_encryption` was `MD5`. As of version 10, you can configure either `MD5` or `scram-sha-256` (recommended). The error is telling you you are trying to connect to a version of postgresql using `scram-sha-256` password encryption from a setup that supports only `MD5`. (you need a newer version of `libpq`).

Comment: Uninstall the ancient PostgreSQL software installed in addition to the current one.